# Windows command FOR /F isn't working?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

I'm trying to use the FOR command in Windows XP's command line. I have a file temp.txt with 3 lines:

```
temp1
temp2
temp3
```

And I'm typing the following command at the prompt:

```
for /F %p in (temp.txt) do echo Testing %p
```

Nothing comes back. If I remove the /F parameter, the output is `Testing temp.txt`.

As far as I can determine, I'm using the command exactly as it is [documented by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true). I've checked my registry to make sure Command Extensions are on, and even started a new shell with `cmd /e:on` to be doubly sure.

What am I doing wrong?

**Yes, I was doing something wrong.**

The file temp.txt wasn't created from scratch, I just edited it to put in my test content. Unfortunately when I created the file the first time, I saved it with a UTF-8 marker at the front.  Recreating the file as plain text solved the problem.

Comment: hate to ask the stupid question, but are you sure you're in the same directory as `temp.txt` in the command line?  Can't think of any reason it wouldn't work outside of that.

Comment: Yes, I am in the directory. I also tested with a full path to the file, but I'm trying to eliminate as many irrelevant details as possible.

Comment: use echo ... > or copy con  to quickly create a file for testing, then you'd have seen it work, then you could use xxd or od and examine the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is the desired result:

```
H:\>for /F %p in (temp.txt) do echo Testing %p

H:\>echo Testing temp1
Testing temp1

H:\>echo Testing temp2
Testing temp2

H:\>echo Testing temp3
Testing temp3
```

If so, have you been testing other batch files, or have you redirected input/output?  If you're doing this as part of a larger project, might you have changed delimiters or the skip parameter to the FOR command?  Is it possible that there are non-printable characters in the front of your temp.txt file?  I've gotten this to work on a couple of different computers, including a 2k3 Server Std. box...I can't help but think there's either trouble with your input file or defaults being set without your knowledge.

Comment: I figured out the problem before I saw this answer, but since it includes the actual solution (non-printable characters in the front) I'm selecting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of testing with `echo`, which simply takes the names in the set as-is (even if the file doesn't exist), try something like `type`:

```
for %p in (temp.txt) do type %p
```

That will show you what the shell "sees". (Note that /F with a nonexistent file will complain about not finding the file, but maybe you have more than one temp.txt around?)

Comment: Yes, that command shows me the contents of temp.txt. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm unclear what I was supposed to learn by trying it.

Comment: Just establishing a baseline, that the file is there, readable, and the right one. Next I was going to ask how you created the file -- I used good old `copy con` -- but I see you've figured it out. The BOM strikes again! I will have to kick it up a notch in the psychic debugging list.

Answer (score 2):

The proper approach is this:

```
for %%a in (temp1 temp2 temp3) do (
  echo Testing %%a
  for /f %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
)
```

Or you could do this:

```
for /l %%n in (1,1,3) do (
  for %%a in (temp%%n) do (
    echo Testing %%a
    for /f %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
  )
)
```

Another variantion is:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
  echo Testing %%a
  for /f %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
)
```

Etc...

If there are spaces in the filenames then you'll have to use 'usebackq' with 'FOR/F' and wrap the filenames in double-quotes like this:

```
...
for /f "usebackq" %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%b
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spend hours on this. You need to replace temp.txt with 'type temp.txt':

```
for /F %p in ('type temp.txt') do echo Testing %p
```